# I don't understand why this code won't run

Tags: computer-science

i am new to c# so i apologize if this is an easy fix. But i cant seem to debug my code. everything looks fine to me. it's so confusing. i like python alot better. Can someone please help? like, it half runs but not fully and idk what to do :( :( :(

any help would be much appreciated-- even ways to improve. I'm thinking it has something to do with the output but not sure

```
// Creates a BoatLicense class
// And instantiates three BoatLicense objects
// The price of a licence is $25 if the boat motor is 50 HP or under
// and $38 if the HP is over 50
// Boat licenses are issued with numbers starting with 200801
using System;
public class DebugSeven4
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      const int STARTINGNUM = 200801;
      BoatLicense[] license = new BoatLicense[3];
      int x;
      for(x = 0; x < license.Length; ++x)
      {
         license[x] = new BoatLicense();
         license[x].LicenseNum = (x + STARTINGNUM).ToString();
      }
      license[0].State = "WI";
      license[1].State = "MI";
      license[2].State = "MN";
      license[0].MotorSizeInHP = 30;
      license[1].MotorSizeInHP = 50;
      license[2].MotorSizeInHP = 100;
      for(x = 0; x < license.Length; ++x)
        Display(license[x]);
   }
   static void Display(BoatLicense lic)
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Boat #{0} from {1} has a {2} HP motor.", lic.LicenseNum, lic.State, lic.MotorSizeInHP);
      Console.WriteLine("The price for the license is {0}", lic.Price.ToString("C2"));
   }
}
class BoatLicense
{
      public const int HPCUTOFF = 50;
      public const double LOWFEE = 25.00;
      public const double HIGHFEE = 38.00;
      private string licenseNum;
      private string state;
      private int motorSizeInHP;
      private double price;
      public string LicenseNum
      {
         get
         {
            return licenseNum;
         }
         set
         {
            licenseNum = value;
         }
      }
      public string State
      {
         get
         {
            return state;
         }
         set
         {
            state = value;
         }
      }
      public int MotorSizeInHP
      {
         get
         {
            return motorSizeInHP;
         }
         set
         {
            motorSizeInHP = value;
            if(MotorSizeInHP <= HPCUTOFF)
               price = LOWFEE;
            else
               price = HIGHFEE;
         }
      }
      public double Price
      {
         get
         {
            return price;
         }
      }

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

it takes time to learn something new. Don't give up. 
In order to help you, you need to let us know what is the error message. 
Microsoft has a good support document on how to debug code.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debugging-absolute-beginners?view=vs-2019

Once you read through the article, please update the questions with the error message.